# webdriver select first sibling based on nth sibling condition

Tags: css, xpath, webdriver

i'm writing a test case in a grid based software
I'm mostly using css selectors to select elements and perform clicking

[image]

based on the image - I'm selecting the right circled element (base don a css class that displays the blue dot ), now, based on this condition, I want to select the first sibling element - which is a "plus", basically that would open the sub grid further and allow me to run further testing

I can't seem to be able to do that -

assuming that I'm using the following sample html

```
<div class="td">
    <a class="opener">
    ....
    </a>
</div>
<div class="td">
...
</div>
<div class="td">
...
</div>
<div class="td">
...
</div>
<div class="td">
...
</div>
<div class="td">
    <a class="round-solid">
    ...
    </a>
</div>
```

I can select "round-solid" - based on this, how do I select "opener" element ?

I only want the opener element for which a specific column contains the "round-solid" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='round-solid']/../preceding-sibling::div/a[@class='opener']"));
```